# how to pass multiple objects back to parent viewcontroller with delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the delegate method to pass data back to the parent with a statement such as

```
[self.delegate viewControllerDismissed:data1];
```

This works well. Now I have a need to send more data. Can I use something like

```
[self.delegate viewControllerDismissed:data1 with:data2];
```

And if so, what does the protocol etc look like? Or do I just pass everything back through and array? I can't find any examples with two parameters

Comment: Why not call the delegate several times? Otherwise add another delegate that accepts an NSArray.

Comment: How would I structure things if I call the delegate several time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the model of data or array or dictionary example in swift what i am using

```
class Place: NSObject {
  var placeId: String = ""
  var primaryText: String = ""
  var secondaryText: String = ""
  var latitude: Double = 0
  var longitude: Double = 0
}
```

then call delegate method with created place

```
delegate?.didSelectPlace(place: placeObject)
```

Comment: Best way is create a model and passed throught a delegate!!!!
OR
Use NSNotificationCenter and pass a userInfo dict

Answer (score 0):

Different ways to do this.

**Idea #1:** Add a method to the class of the delegate object, that can take all the data as arguments.

```
@interface MyParentViewController : NSViewController
- (void)someDataFromTheChildVC:(NSString *)data1 moreData:(NSArray *)data2;
@end
```

In the child view controller, make sure you cast the degelate to `MyParentViewController`, so you have access to the new method:

```
MyParentViewController *parent = (MyParentViewController *)self.delegate;
[parent someDataFromTheChildVC:@"blah" moreData:someArray];
```

**Idea #2:** Put all the data you want to pass back into a dictionary, then call your usual `viewControllerDismissed`:

```
NSDictionary *data = @{
    @"data1": @"blah",
    @"data2": someArray
};
[self.delegate viewControllerDismissed:data];
```

You don't need a protocol for this.